# Get first element of the first sequence of length N of consecutively increasing numbers in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to solve the following. Suppose we have some data that look like this:

```
d1 <- seq(0, 3000, length.out = 1000)
d2 <- cos(seq(0, 6*pi, length.out = 1000))*rev(seq(0, 1, length.out = 1000))
dd <- as.data.frame(cbind(d1, d2))
```

[image]

I have the need to detect from `d2` the first element of the first sequence of length 20 of consecutively increasing numbers. In the figure above it would be somewhere around `d1 = 500`. My current approach is based on this function:

```
getFirstBeforeSequence <- function(x, y, len){
a1 <- cbind(lapply(split(y, cumsum(c(1, diff(y) < 0))), length))
a2 <- which(a1 > len)[1]-1
a3 <- sum(unlist(a1)[1:a2])+1
a3  
}
```

This function gives me the desired output, the element is in position 164 and has occurred when `d1 = 489.4895`:

```
getFirstBeforeSequence(dd$d1, dd$d2, 20)
# 164
dd$d1[164]
# 489.4895
```

However, I have the impression that my solution is overly complex and I'm pretty sure that others will have better solutions. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of `sign(diff(cumsum(data)))` will do it for you.

Comment: I think there is an inconsistency in your column names, in your data definition `d1` is the cosine (so [-1, 1]). but then you write `dd$d1[164]`

Comment: @Michele I copied the wrong definitions of `d1` and `d2`. Now they are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a stab:

```
getFirstBefore<-function(x,len){
  r<-rle(sign(diff(x)))
  n<-which(r$lengths>=len & r$values==1)
  if(length(n)==0)
    return(-1)
  1+sum(r$lengths[seq_len(n[1]-1)])
}
```

It's more efficient than the original, but there's probably still room for improvement:

```
microbenchmark(
  getFirstBeforeSequence(dd$d1,dd$d2,20),
  getFirstBefore(dd$d2,20))

# Unit: microseconds
#                                      expr      min       lq   median        uq
#  getFirstBeforeSequence(dd$d1, dd$d2, 20) 2433.174 2464.457 2486.186 2502.2005
#                 getFirstBefore(dd$d2, 20)  181.354  187.081  192.808  196.6805
#       max neval
#  9932.534   100
#   239.700   100
```

Comment: nice method! I was thinking c(1:20,19) includes 20 consecutive increasing numbers? if so, using `diff` and then checking its length against 20 it would be discarded. Even though it may be just a matter of the OP preference

Comment: Yes, it depends what "20 consecutive increasing numbers" means.  It also rejects `c(2,1:20)`, so at least it's consistent.

Comment: yes, of course. probably they are (mathematically) 19 consecutive, I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

This is slower, but gives a completely different approach:

```
firstOfSequence <- function(x, len){

  v <- paste0(sign(diff(x))+1L, collapse="")
  regexpr(paste0("([2])\\1{", len-1L, "}"), v)

}


> microbenchmark(
+   firstOfSequence(dd$d2, 20),
+   getFirstBefore(dd$d2, 20))
Unit: microseconds
                       expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 firstOfSequence(dd$d1, 20) 978.181 981.3875 982.9910 998.7060 1111.597   100
  getFirstBefore(dd$d1, 20) 191.147 196.5990 200.4475 205.0975  333.865   100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
y <- dd$d1

# indices of pits and peaks
pit <- which(diff(sign(diff(y))) == 2) + 1
peak <- which(diff(sign(diff(y))) == -2) + 1

# distance between peak and pit -> length of increase
len_incr <- peak - pit

# index of first pit from which a consecutive increase in 20 'steps' starts
idx <- pit[(len_incr > 20) == TRUE][1]

# corresponding x-value
dd$d2[idx]
# [1] 489.4895    


# similar approach but let 'turnpoint' find pits and peaks.
library(pastecs)
tp <- turnpoints(y)
pit <- which(tp$pits == TRUE)
peak <- which(tp$peaks == TRUE)
len_incr <- peak - pit
idx <- pit[(len_incr > 20) == TRUE][1]
dd$d2[idx]
# [1] 489.4895
```

Comment: +1 for `pastecs`. since you use 2 `diff`, shouldn't it be + 2 when you calculate `pit` and `peak`?

Comment: Michele, It seemed that +1 was enough...;)