# Finding Row number of Consecutive decreasing values in data

Tags: r, dplyr, diff

I need to detect from data the first element of the first sequence of length 5 of consecutively decreasing numbers. There is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337105/get-first-element-of-the-first-sequence-of-length-n-of-consecutively-increasing?rq=1) here but when I applied to my data it failed.

```
set.seed(201)  
az <- c(sort(runif(10,0,0.9),decreasing = T),sort(runif(3,-0.3,0),decreasing = T),sort(runif(3,-0.3,0),decreasing = F),sort(runif(4,-0.3,0),decreasing = T),sort(runif(4,-0.3,0),decreasing = F),sort(runif(6,-0.3,0),decreasing = T))   
tz <- seq(1,length(az))
df <- data.frame(tz,az=round(az,2))
```

[image]

In the figure above it would be somewhere around tz = 25.

The post says that this function need to improve and so far I cannot get my desired result!

```
  getFirstBefore<-function(x,len){
    r<-rle(sign(diff(x)))
    n<-which(r$lengths>=len & r$values<0)
    if(length(n)==0)
      return(-1)
    1+sum(r$lengths[seq_len(n[1]-1)])
  }

df1 <- df%>%
mutate(cns_tz=getFirstBefore(az,5))

 tz    az cns_tz
#1   1  0.56      4
#2   2  0.55      4
#3   3  0.33      4
#4   4  0.33      4
#5   5  0.26      4
#6   6  0.15      4
#7   7  0.12      4
#8   8  0.09      4
#9   9  0.04      4
#10 10  0.04      4
#11 11 -0.10      4
#12 12 -0.12      4
#13 13 -0.16      4
#14 14 -0.16      4
#15 15 -0.14      4
#16 16 -0.14      4
#17 17 -0.13      4
#18 18 -0.15      4
#19 19 -0.22      4
#20 20 -0.30      4
#21 21 -0.12      4
#22 22 -0.12      4
#23 23 -0.11      4
#24 24 -0.07      4
#25 25 -0.05      4
#26 26 -0.09      4
#27 27 -0.10      4
#28 28 -0.15      4
#29 29 -0.17      4
#30 30 -0.22      4
```

Comment: Isn't position 4 correct also?

Comment: @Sotos actually I am just looking from the tail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
n <- 5
v1 <- setDT(df)[sign(az)<0,  .I[which(.N==n)] , rleid(c(1, sign(diff(az))))]$V1[1L]
v1
#[1] 26
df[, cnz_tz := v1]
```

Or another option is `shift` with `Reduce`

```
setDT(df)[, cnz_tz := .I[Reduce(`&`, shift((az - shift(az, fill=az[1])) < 0,
                            0:4, type = "lead", fill=FALSE)) & sign(az) < 0][1]]
```

---

We can also use `rleid` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
v1 <- df %>% 
         group_by(rl= rleid(c(1, sign(diff(az))))) %>% 
         mutate(rn =  sign(az) < 0 & n()==5) %>% 
        .$rn %>%
         which() %>% 
         head(., 1)
v1
#[1] 26
df %>%
   mutate(cnz_tz = v1)
```

Answer (score 7):

I would sort every 5 consecutive values, and see if that matches with the unsorted data. Then find the first occurance of such a match:

```
set.seed(123)
test <- rnorm(100)

decr <- sapply(seq_along(test),function(x){all(sort(test[x:(x+5)],decreasing = T) == test[x:(x+5)])})
firstdecr <- min(which(decr)):(min(which(decr))+5)
plot(test)
lines(firstdecr, test[firstdecr], col="red")
```

Only flaw I can see if there are equal values in a 5 value epoch, but you could also test for that.

Comment: your solution is also elegant but how do you connect to my data with `dplyr` solution?

Comment: add a flag with something like `orgdata[min(which(decr)),'flag'] <- 1`
or add the whole `decr` result to the data frame.

Answer (score 3):

My naive pure-dplyr approach would be to compute a rolling sum of signs for differences and identify rows where the next five diffs have a negative sign. I say "naive" because this solution does not use `rle` for detecting streaks.

```
library(dplyr)
diff_details <- df %>%
  mutate(diff = c(0, diff(az)),
         diff_sign = sign(diff),
         rolling_signs = cumsum(diff_sign),
         next_five = lead(rolling_signs, 5) - rolling_signs)
diff_details
#>    tz    az  diff diff_sign rolling_signs next_five
#> 1   1  0.56  0.00         0             0        -4
#> 2   2  0.55 -0.01        -1            -1        -4
#> 3   3  0.33 -0.22        -1            -2        -4
#> 4   4  0.33  0.00         0            -2        -5
#> 5   5  0.26 -0.07        -1            -3        -4
#> 6   6  0.15 -0.11        -1            -4        -4
#> 7   7  0.12 -0.03        -1            -5        -4
#> 8   8  0.09 -0.03        -1            -6        -4
#> 9   9  0.04 -0.05        -1            -7        -3
#> 10 10  0.04  0.00         0            -7        -2
#> 11 11 -0.10 -0.14        -1            -8        -1
#> 12 12 -0.12 -0.02        -1            -9         1
#> 13 13 -0.16 -0.04        -1           -10         1
#> 14 14 -0.16  0.00         0           -10         0
#> 15 15 -0.14  0.02         1            -9        -2
#> 16 16 -0.14  0.00         0            -9        -1
#> 17 17 -0.13  0.01         1            -8        -2
#> 18 18 -0.15 -0.02        -1            -9         0
#> 19 19 -0.22 -0.07        -1           -10         2
#> 20 20 -0.30 -0.08        -1           -11         4
#> 21 21 -0.12  0.18         1           -10         2
#> 22 22 -0.12  0.00         0           -10         1
#> 23 23 -0.11  0.01         1            -9        -1
#> 24 24 -0.07  0.04         1            -8        -3
#> 25 25 -0.05  0.02         1            -7        -5
#> 26 26 -0.09 -0.04        -1            -8        NA
#> 27 27 -0.10 -0.01        -1            -9        NA
#> 28 28 -0.15 -0.05        -1           -10        NA
#> 29 29 -0.17 -0.02        -1           -11        NA
#> 30 30 -0.22 -0.05        -1           -12        NA
```

Instead of identifying streaks in a sequence, we look at a cumulative sum of the signs of the differences in `rolling_signs`. `next_five` computes the difference in `rolling_signs` over the next five rows. When `next_five` is -5, then the next five rows have decreasing changes.

```
(diff_details$next_five %in% -5) %>% which %>% max
#> [1] 25
```

Each of the steps/columns could be abstracted into a function, like:

```
cum_diff_signs <- function(xs, window) {
  rolling_signs <- cumsum(sign(c(0, diff(xs))))
  next_diffs <- dplyr::lead(rolling_signs, window) - rolling_signs
  next_diffs
}
cum_diff_signs(df$az, 5)
#>  [1] -4 -4 -4 -5 -4 -4 -4 -4 -3 -2 -1  1  1  0 -2 -1 -2  0  2  4  2  1 -1
#> [24] -3 -5 NA NA NA NA NA
(cum_diff_signs(df$az, 5) %in% -5) %>% which %>% max
#> [1] 25
```